# Format number of decimals in cells containing complex numbers

Tags: macros, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet containing both real and complex numbers. Some of them are like

```
0.48686
```

while others are like

```
4.85609+j3.24184
```

I am trying to round them, in order to have only two decimal places.

While Format > Cells works on the real numbers, it doesn't on the complex ones, because LibreOffice interprets them as a string.

I have looked up in google, but couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

I wanted to know if there was anyone who had already developed a macro for that, before trying to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could round the complex number by combining the [**`ROUND()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ROUND_function) and the [**`COMPLEX()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COMPLEX_function) functions:

[image]

`A3` has the formula

> `=COMPLEX(A1;A2)`

while `A4` has

> `=COMPLEX( ROUND(A1;2) ; ROUND(A2;2) )`

*(adapting a [solution from a german ms office forum](http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic216102_0_0_asc.php) to OOo.Calc / LO Calc)*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this modifies the result, not only the result shown, which is generally not wanted.